# image fails to load using cezpdf

Tags: php

the same question was not addressed here several years ago. Anyone with an idea please help.

```
function hello_world()
{
    $this->load->library('cezpdf');
    $image =BASEPATH.'img/screenshot.png';
    $image =base_url().'screenshot.png';
    $this->cezpdf->ezImage($image);
```

Comment: `echo $image;`. Run the link from browser, check if image is rendered in browser.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. The function will accept either a direct file system path, or a URL. If you use a URL it will copy it to a tmp directory on the server. Check to make sure that directory is writeable. 2. The function uses the GD library and perhaps you don't have PHP GD available on your environment.

Comment: it doesn't load the image

Comment: the GD library is enabled